# module file name error in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to install sql developer on windows7 but I got this message "unable to set the current directory based on the module file name". how to fix this error?

Comment: Just a guess -- do you have the full Java JDK installed and appropriate environment variables set?  I think the SQL*Developer checks for a full JDK but maybe your Java JDK is partly corrupted.

Comment: I have checked on my Java version. I ran the command java -version and I found out that I was using java version 1.8.